# SQL Multipart Incorrect Syntax, Aggregate Function, Multipart Identifier can not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying for several hours to teach myself and learn on how to list all customers and the orders placed by each of them with my dummy test data. I want to return the CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderTypeName, and the count "OrderCount"

I have tried a few different ways and techniques found online but I keep running into similar/different problems all relating to apparent simple solutions that I just cannot figure out.

Here is my current query.

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, t.OrderTypeName
FROM 
    tblCustomer c, tblOrder o, tblOrderType t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         o.CustomerID, COUNT(o.CustomerID) AS OrderCount
     FROM
         tblOrder o, tblCustomer c
     WHERE 
         o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

this one is currently giving the error of Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago). And you should most definitely not **mix** the two styles - use the comma-separated list of tables and then mix in an `INNER JOIN` ... switch to the proper ANSI JOIN syntax - you won't regret it!

Comment: You have to specify the columns on which you want to perform the join. That is the only error. See Dibster's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing old-style joins with comma-separated lists of tables and the proper ANSI standard `INNER JOIN` - but you're not providing any **join condition**.

My suggestion: get used to the ANSI standard and use it - all the time!

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, t.OrderTypeName
FROM 
    tblCustomer c
INNER JOIN 
    tblOrder o ON ..(what links tblOrder and tblCustomer??) ....
INNER JOIN
    tblOrderType t ON ....(what links OrderType and Order??) ....
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         o.CustomerID, COUNT(o.CustomerID) AS OrderCount
     FROM
         tblOrder o
     INNER JOIN
         tblCustomer c ON .....(missing join condition again).....
     WHERE 
         o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID) x ON .....(again: missing join condition here).....
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

Comment: Thank you the clear explaination Marc, I guess I was confusing myself of the proper ways when looking through my Microsoft SQL server 2012 "A Beginners Guide" and the online explainations and tutorials I found, using a little bit a both. I tried both what you showed me and what Dibstar posted below and they both worked, although Dibstar's is less code. What would be the named difference here between yours and his and the benefit of one over the other if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption in terms of how the ordertype table connects to the orders table:

```
SELECT 
c.CustomerID
,c.CustomerName
,t.OrderTypeName
,COUNT(o.customer_id) as num_orders
FROM tblCustomer c
INNER JOIN tblOrder o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN tblOrderType t ON t.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY
c.CustomerID
,c.CustomerName
,t.OrderTypeName
ORDER BY 
c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `JOIN`, you need to specify the field in which you are joining those two tables:

for example:

```
select t1.a,t2.b from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id= t2.id
```

So I guess you haven't been reading the guides you said correctly.

For a solution to your question, you need to choose which type of syntax you wan to use. the comma-separated (very old) or the one providing the `join condition` (recommended).